# Upload multiple files to AWS S3 bucket without overwriting existing objects

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am very new to AWS technology.

I want to add some files to an existing S3 bucket without overwriting existing objects. I am using Spring Boot technology for my project.

Can anyone please suggest how can we add/upload multiple files without overwriting existing objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS S3 supports object versioning in the bucket, in which for use case of uploading same file, S3 will keep all files within the bucket with different version rather than overwriting it.

This can be configured using AWS Console or CLI to enable the Versioning feature. You may want to refer this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectVersioning.html) for more info.

Comment: When I upload the new files, the existing files are overwritten. That is my issue.

Comment: Same issue... I want to add a new object to an existing folder, without overwriting OTHER objects with different names

Answer (score 1):

You probably already found an answer to this, but if you're using the CDK or the CLI you can specify a `destinationKeyPrefix`. If you want multiple folders in an S3, which was my case, the folder name will be your `destinationKeyPrefix`.